# Redirecting all domains to a single https domain

Tags: php, apache, ssl-certificate

I recently bought a hosting plan which provides three domains. Since there is only one version of my website, the idea is to redirect all the domains to one single domain ( I think this is also more SEO friendly). So my question is : How can I achieve that ? (Is it as easy as changing something in the .htaccess file?). And Is it possible to buy one SSL certificate for a domain and redirect all other domains ( which have no ssl certificates) to it ?

Comment: Please clarify what you've tried so far. Additionally, this might not be a programming issue after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

one damain - one certificate :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain3.com
    Redirect / https://www.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This redirects all http requests to the one domain for which you got a SSL certificate